# With Javascript can you make browser to let you type bookmark name and it loads the page for you?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, browser-addons

So, I am not a fan of using Mouse unless something cant be done with the keyboard through shortcuts.

My internet explorer is made to search in Google when keywords are typed in the Address bar. 
Is there any setting I could in the browser that would let me type a bookmark name(autocomplete would be great) and the page loads.

If not, any browser plugins to rescue?

I can try this but just want to make sure before i start doing so: 
Can javascript bookmarklet be written to have such a dictionary of [bookmarkname] - [url] built from the browsers bookmark list. Then it should be easy enough to navigate to that bookmarklet from keyboard and then type my bookmark name and javascript in the bookmarklet redirects me away to the URL?

Comment: Use a decent browser like Chrome.

Comment: Does Chrome give me that functionality. If not, what makes you call it "Decent"?

Comment: @vinaycasyani: You can type the bookmark name (or even part of it) and it will open a suggestion list containing relevant bookmarks. Just press your down key until it's selected and press Enter.

Comment: @pimvdb: Agreed. I am a fool but my Company uses a sharepoint site with which some part of UI looks crap on chrome. I am aware of the browser war stories. Just realized IE 9 supports it the sameway from Marc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a plugin.

Hit <kbd>Alt-A</kbd> and then just start typing the name of your bookmark. The menu selection should follow what you've typed. if your bookmark is in a subfolder in the bookmarks menu, you can use <kbd>-></kbd> and <kbd><-</kbd> to navigate in/out of those subfolders. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're on the bookmark you want, and it'll load up.

---

as it turns out, IE9's address bar is now copying FF's awesome bar and will search the bookmarks, so an <kbd>Alt-D</kbd> followed by the name of a bookmark will show bookmarks in the search results under the bar.

Comment: It seems to be `Alt-C` on IE9.

Comment: alt-A on my install. must be variable depending on what other menus you've got, and what they're using for shortcut keys.

Comment: Lets correct this: you meant Alt-D right. I could do it with Alt+D which edits the address bar, while Alt-A navigates to the Favorites menu. [I am using IE9]

Comment: I believe Alt-D is universal. Can you edit your Answer Marc so I may approve. You may put a disclaimer of browser dependent. But I beleive Alt D should be universal.

Comment: alt-D puts the cursor into the address bar. alt-A selects the favorites menu. Didn't realize that IE's address bar now searches the bookmarks... I've barely used IE9 since I installed it - prefer to use FF/Chrome.